# Is there a CSS workaround for Opera's bug with visibility transition?

Tags: css, opera, css-transitions

Here is a fiddle for start: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/A7QX9/

The problem: in Opera when you animate the transition for `visibility` property (usually along with the `opacity`) it's not animated properly: the `visibility` is changed always at the end of transition, so when the block is appearing it's not appearing smoothly.

So, the question: is there any CSS-only workaround for this Opera's bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I formulated the question and thought for a while, I've found the answer myself.

And came up with a solution.

So, going step-by-step:

1. Let's look at the case when you need to show the block which is hidden at the start.
2. When you toggle the `opacity` and `visibility` with a transition, the block stays with `visibility: hidden` while the transition is in the run. So, you don't need to use transition for `visibility` here.
3. But when you hide the block again, you need to toggle the `visibility` at the end of the transition, so you need the transition here apparently.
4. So, at the selector where the block is hidden you must have the transition for the `opacity` and in the selector where it's shown, you don't need the transition.

Here is a fiddle I've made with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/A7QX9/1/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fiddle.  I had an issue with animations and opacity on Opera.  After looking at your fiddle, it led me to the right answer.  Use vendor prefix for the animation declaration but leave off the vendor prefix when declaring opacity within the animation.  This is really obvious in hindsight, but it's sometimes uncertain to me when vendor prefixes are necessary and when they're not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Current implementation of transitions in Opera is based on an [older version of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) saying that for transitioning visibility "1 is "visible" and all other values are "hidden"."

So if you try transitioning from "hidden" to "visible" then you won't see the element until underlying 0-1 range representing transition reaches value 1.
At the same time, if you are transitioning from "visible" to "hidden" then element will disappear as soon as transition has started as value will be <1.

The behavior that you expect is specified in the ["draft" version of the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/) which says that "0 is "hidden" and all other values are "visible".".

Good news though - Opera 12 will include fix for this bug. Expect to see testing build with a fix on [Desktop Team blog](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/) soon.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation! Good to hear that this issue would be fixed.